# Select statement to table with percentage column names

Tags: postgresql

I am selecting data from one table that have percentage sign in some column names like:

```
| name | val% | vale2% |
```

This table is ofted use with `select * from table`, but in this case I need only the field names with percentage sing, when I run a select in query tool of pgadmin this notice this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: SELECT val% as value, val2% as value2 from table
```

How I can run this query and get only val% and val% without the rest of fields.

NOTE: I can change the database structure, only query it data

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT [val%] as value, [val2%] as value2 from table`?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the names, like `SELECT "val%" as value, "val2%" as value2  from ...`?

Comment: @RDFozz SELECT "val%" as value...works for me, thank you

Comment: In general, you should avoid such column names if you can help it.  In my experience, it only results in confusion when something does not work because of the lack of quoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moved from comment to answer, as it seemed to resolve the OP's problem:

It sounds like the actual column names are causing your problem. If so, then you need to quote them somehow. Depending on the settings for your database:

```
SELECT "val%" as value, "val2%" as value2 from table
```

may work. In some SQL variants, you can use square brackets `[]` to quote column names that conflict with language keywords and operators:

```
SELECT [val%] as value, [val2%] as value2 from table
```

Comment: do you know how I can do dot notation when there is a space?, example: x.val but with percentage sign and spage between both? return x['val %'];

Comment: The same quoting that worked with a % should work with a space: `SELECT "val %" as value, "val 2 %" as value2 from table` (assuming postgresql allows it at all, which it must if that's the column name).

Comment: sorry I have explained bad, I am using GraphQL, and I need to get a fieldname with x.myfield but my field have spaces beetween val and % and x."val %" get an error in graphql editor

Comment: I don't know GraphQL, so I can't really help you there. Not clear if the problem is with retrieving the data youo want for postgresql with GraphQL, or with using the same field names. If the problem is the field names you get back from postgresql, then alias them (as in your example above, where the column names in the results would be "value" and "value2".